# check the source of activation of extension in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for visual studio code. My extension has several activation events. So in the activate call back how I can differentiate the source of activation? for ex., Extension get activate if a workspace contains a specific folder or if a command is given. In activate call back I want to execute different initialization for different activation. Is there any API to get this info?

Ex:
In `package.json` two activation events are given by

```json
...
  "activationEvents": [
    "workspaceContains:foo",
    "*"
  ],
...
```

In the `extension.ts` file the corresponding activate callback will be defined.

```ts
...
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext): any {
...
}
...
```

In the above scenario, `activate()` will be called in one of the 2 events:

1. If vscode opens.
2. If a folder is opened and contains `foo` file in the root directory.

what I want is like this:

```ts
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext): any {
    if(/*activated by "*" event*/) {
        Init1();
    }
    else if(/*activated by "workspaceContains" event*/) {
        Init2();
    }
}
```

This is just a pseudo code. But This is what the whole point is.

Comment: Add an example of what you are talking about (e.g. one of your callbacks).

Comment: Thank you for the response Mike. I added pseudo code to explain what I want. I hope that explains what I needed.

Comment: OK, I see, but I believe there is no way to tell apart the 2 events (however `*` is a catch-all event, it covers also the `workspaceContains` case, no?). I was speculating on workspace callbacks, where you get a document and check the languageId to see if that is for a particular file type you can handle.

Comment: ya correct. * will cover workspaceContains . But I don't want some part of code initialization to be done an all event. I think I have to decide only to use * event. check file presence in the activate() then from there I can go on. anyway thank you mike. will it make sense to file a feature request for this?

Comment: adding an answer for you to accept...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lined out in the comments there is no way to differentiate between the two activation events. In fact the activation is done by matching one of the patterns in package.json. Other than for documents there is no indication **which** pattern was actually matched. That's probably too fine grained, hence I have doubts that creating a feature request for that will have a chance.